# mysterious 0 when using \formatdate

Tags: formatting, datetime

I'm writing my resume using a template and I wanted my some of the dates to be presented as e.g. 14th October I got it displayed like that using.

```
\usepackage[UKenglish,nodayofweek]{datetime}
```

and

```
\formatdate{14}{10}
```

but it prints the date as "14th October, 0". I'm guessing it's printing an empty year but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm  also going to need to print some dates as just "month + Year" is there a way to print that as well in the same document easily or should I just type it out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A year is required in the arguments to `\formatdate`: `\formatdate{<day>}{<month>}{<year>}`. Can you make a minimal example that shows the mysterious 0?

Comment: `\formatdate` takes three arguments day month year `\formatdate{14}{10}{2013}`

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own formats day + month or month + year with `\newdateformat`and use with `\today`, `\SetDate`(of `advdate` package) or a `\formatdate`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish,nodayofweek]{datetime}

\newdateformat{DM}{\ordinal{DAY} \monthname[\THEMONTH]}
\newdateformat{MY}{\monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

{\Large\verb|\today|}\bigskip

{\tt datetime} default  \dotfill  \today 

\LaTeX\ default (\verb|\usdate|) \dotfill \usdate\today

Day and month (\verb|\DM|) \dotfill \DM\today  

Month and year (\verb|\MY|) \dotfill \MY\today 

\bigskip{\Large\verb|\formatdate{28}{11}{2014}|}\bigskip

{\tt datetime} default \dotfill \longdate\formatdate{28}{11}{2014}

\LaTeX{} default (\verb|\usdate|) \dotfill \usdate\formatdate{28}{11}{2014}

Day and month (\verb|\DM|) \dotfill \DM\formatdate{28}{11}{2014}

Month and year (\verb|\MY|) \dotfill \MY\formatdate{28}{11}{2014}

\end{document}
```